# Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries, runtime-error

I am using Linux x86_64 machine to build my program.
I have linked a shared library to an executable. In my project I am calling a function which has declared `vector<string>` inside the function. My program gets killed when that function gets called.
When debugging through GDB below is the output I get.

```
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x00002aaaac4d2be7 in OC_Catalog_c::File_ToText (this=0x611aa0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:87
87              : _Tp_alloc_type(__a), _M_start(0), _M_finish(0), _M_end_of_storage(0)
(gdb) bt
0  0x00002aaaac4d2be7 in OC_Catalog_c::File_ToText (this=0x611aa0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:87
```

Is this issue of compilation of my shared library?? 
Banged my head enough on it. Please help.

-Chaks

Adding more info for your queries:
Yes,function that i am calling File_ToText is a virtual function in class OC_Catalog_c.
A member variable of other class has object of class OC_Catalog_c which also have virtual function File_ToText.Using that object I am calling File_ToText function of OC_Catlog_c from virtual function File_ToText.
I will show a code snippet:

```
class Oc_Catalog_c  
{
    virtual vector<string>  File_ToText             (void) const; 
}

class B
{
    const OC_Catalog_c*         m_pCatalog;
    virtual vector<string>  File_ToText             (void) const; 
}

vector<string> B::File_ToText( void ) const
{
    vector<string> a_SubData;
    a_SubData = m_pCatalog->File_ToText();
}
```

Comment: Please start with pasting a snippet for starter, and tell more about the library.

Comment: What options do you use when compiling with g++?  Are you also building the shared library or did you get it somewhere else?

Comment: It might also be useful to know which processor you are running on, and which linux distro and version you are using.

Comment: Its Intel Xeon processor. I am building shared libraries also. Function calls are in shared library. I am using automake to build my project options most options are default. I have made a shared library by linking various static libraries. Each static libraries  has these options: AM_LIBTOOLFLAGS = --tag=-static and -fPIC to tell specifically.

Comment: FWIW, I've had SIGILLs using inline assembly where the assembler can emit opcodes that the host can't execute. Were the libraries compiled on a different machine with -mcpu=native or similar?

Comment: Nope,shared libraries is built on same machine on which i am using it. It contains many static libraries. One of the static library calls global function which is in some other library, whose task is to get message from a  catalog file to publish it in log file.

Comment: If you have code that happens to overwrite a virtual function in the vtable, you can get this sort of thing as well. Try running it in `gdb` and see where it falls over more exactly (compile with `-g`)

Comment: You say you're using an x86_64 machine to build the program; are you in fact running it on some other machine?  If so, there might be lots of explanations; if not, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: No Jonathan i m running it on same machine on which I have build the program.

Comment: OK — I just wondered from your wording.  It was an extreme outside chance, but worth checking.

Comment: Can someone give your suggestion on how to debug this problem. Not getting any clue where is the problem...Please suggest.

Comment: The *very first* GDB command you should execute is `x/i $pc`. That will show you which instruction is generating `SIGILL`. The *second* command should be `disas $pc`.  As a wild guess, you are calling a virtual function on global, that has not been constructed yet, or has already been destructed. Also, I doubt that the `bt` command produced just one frame. You'll do well to *not* omit information that you deem unimportant, but which likely is.

Answer (score 18):

Thank you guys for all your help.
I finally figured out the problem that was causing this error.
Debugging more and tracing the instruction I found that program was failing at ud2a instruction.
I was ignoring one warning  "warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type 'struct sqlrw_request_cb' through '...'; call will abort at runtime".
Resolving these warnings fixed my problem related to SIGILL.
More explanation on this link:
[ud2a instruction causing SIGILL](http://peeterjoot.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/a-fun-and-curious-dig-gcc-generation-of-a-ud2a-instruction-sigill/)

Comment: Once I faced this error when return type of my function was `std::vector<std::string>` but I missed the return statement in my function and ignored the compiler's warning by mistake! :D

Comment: @Sam I can confirm also that forgetting the return statement can be a cause of it. I compiled with clang-11.1.0 and got the exactly same message from LLDB.

Comment: yea, it seems like no one else noticed `vector<string> B::File_ToText( void ) const` function doesn't return anything